# How to determine full names for local Mac filename and remote filname to use SCP

Tags: macos, ssh, directory, filenames, scp

I used SSH to connect to a server and navigate to the folder where I want to store some files from my Mac. I think what I need to do is use SCP to do the copy but I'm not sure exactly about the terminology in the command parameters. And so far everything I've tried gets some sort of "not found" error.

Before logging on to the server the prompt is :

```
Apples-MacBook-Pro-2:~ neiltayl$
```

After logging in and navigating to the folder I want to store things in it is :

```
[neiltayl@cs136 Tracer]$
```

I need to copy several files from the Tracer folder on my local computer to the Tracer folder on cs136 and cannot fathom the correct parts of the respective FROM and TO parts of SCP to make it work.

This is the nearest I got so far;

```
Apples-MacBook-Pro-2:~ neiltayl$ ls  
Applications    Downloads   Music       Tracer  
Desktop     Library     Pictures    c151  
Documents   Movies      Public      dwhelper  
Apples-MacBook-Pro-2:~ neiltayl$ scp ./Tracer/*.* neiltayl@cs136.cs.iusb.edu:Tracer
neiltayl@cs136.cs.iusb.edu's password:   
./Tracer/*.*: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 1):

The scp command is -

```
$ scp File1 username@someting:DIRNAME
```

Here File 1 is the file that you are sending over to the other computer.

DIRNAME is the path to the directory where you want the file to be stored.

In your case the command would be

```
scp -r Tracer neiltayl@cs136:New_Tracer
```

Here Tracer is the folder that contains all the files that you want to copy.

Comment: Hah! So sorry! *.* doesn't work when files have no suffix. I feel a fool.

Comment: Does having no suffix means that they are not in a Folder? please clarify. Option -r recursively copies all the files in a directory.